# Inserting byte() along side strings to SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

So here is the predefined SQL statement that is stored in the DAO file. The values are coming from a class. The picture value is an image converted to a byte(). This class is written in VB.net. I'm in a new job and in my previous i used angular and the entity framework so writing SQL statements is new to me. I'm trying to follow existing examples from co workers but they have never inserted images into the database before so i'm kinda on my own. Yes i know i could just store the files in the server and save the paths to them in the database but for whatever reason my network team wants it stored in the database as blobs. So, here is the SQL statement.

```
"INSERT INTO AuthAccessID" &
                      "(" &
                      "FName," &
                      "MName," &
                      "LName," &
                      "Suffix," &
                      "Address," &
                      "AddressExt," &
                      "City," &
                      "State," &
                      "Zip," &
                      "LawFirm," &
                      "Picture," &
                      "AddedDate," &
                      "AddedBy," &
                      ")" &
                      "VALUES(" &
                      "" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.FName) & ", " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.MName) & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.LName) & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.Suffix) & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.Address) & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.AddressExt) & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.City) & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.State) & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.Zip) & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.LawFirm) & "', " &
                      "'" & pp.Picture & "', " &
                      "'" & pp.AddedDate & "', " &
                      "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.AddedBy) & "')
```

the pp.Picture is the Byte(). The error i'm getting is:

```
Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Byte()'
```

i have googled around but cannot find anything. Does anyone have any idea how to correct this? or is there a better way to write the SQL statement? If i can't get this to work the network team said i can use the server file method but they are really pushing the blob in SQL storage instead. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should absolutely not be building your SQL code like that. DO NOT use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code. ALWAYS use parameters. Parameters can be used for ANY data type so, if you learn how to do it for `Strings`, you automatically know how to do it for `Byte` arrays.

Comment: you should be using [SQL Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instead of concatenating a string

Comment: Using parameters also means that you don't need that `ReplaceApostrophes` method. It also avoids issues with formatting dates and the like.

Comment: But this is the way the lead dev does it and that's how he want's it done. Is there a way to add parameters to the statement i have above? Sorry if that's a dumb question i'm new to writing these statements.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  Do you have some sort of doc i can follow for adding Parameters? Is it possible to add Parameters to the values i have above by using the class?

Comment: *"this is the way the lead dev does it"*. Then I'm afraid that that lead dev is incompetent. As for information on the subject, there's loads out there that you can easily find with a web search. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) is my own take though.

Comment: Thank you. Can I still use the values from my class? I will look into this. The lead dev has been there 24 years maybe it’s just an old method? I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use Parameters to avoid sql injection, make you sql statement easier to write and read, and make sure you are sending the correct datatypes. Parameters will also allow apostrophes. Use the `.Add` method. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

In the code below, I had to guess at the `SqlDbType` and Size. Check your database for the correct information.

Connections and commands are using unmanaged resources. They release these resources in their .Dispose method so this method must be called. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of closing and disposing objects even if there is an error.

I assumed pp was an instance of a class. I gave the class the name Person. Correct this to the real class name.

```vb
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub InsertAuthAccessID(pp As Person)
    Dim sql = "INSERT INTO AuthAccessID (
                  FName,
                  MName,
                  LName,
                  Suffix,
                  Address,
                  AddressExt,
                  City,
                  State,
                  Zip,
                  LawFirm,
                  Picture,
                  AddedDate,
                  AddedBy)
                  VALUES (
                  @FName, 
                  @MName, 
                  @LName, 
                  @Suffix,
                  @Address,
                  @AddressExt,
                  @City,
                  @State,
                  @Zip,
                  @LawFirm,
                  @Picture, 
                  @AddedDate,
                  @AddedBy)"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pp.FName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pp.MName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = pp.LName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Suffix", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = pp.Suffix
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = pp.Address
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AddressExt", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pp.AddressExt
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = pp.City
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pp.State
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Zip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = pp.Zip
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LawFirm", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = pp.LawFirm
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = pp.Picture
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AddedDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = pp.AddedDate
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AddedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pp.AddedBy
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

EDIT:

In older versions of VB that did not support multiline `String` literals, you can use an XML literal instead:

```vb
Dim sql = <sql>
            INSERT INTO AuthAccessID (
              FName,
              MName,
              LName,
              Suffix,
              Address,
              AddressExt,
              City,
              State,
              Zip,
              LawFirm,
              Picture,
              AddedDate,
              AddedBy)
              VALUES (
              @FName, 
              @MName, 
              @LName, 
              @Suffix,
              @Address,
              @AddressExt,
              @City,
              @State,
              @Zip,
              @LawFirm,
              @Picture, 
              @AddedDate,
              @AddedBy)
           </sql>

Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
      cmd As New SqlCommand(sql.Value, cn)
```

Comment: Thank you this was perfect. My connection to the database is actually declared in a different area. In the code behind page this sql statement will be called once the form data is assigned to the instance of the class. So I can just drop the connection part and use the parameters still in the statement when it’s passed to the instance right?

Comment: Also with this code i'm getting the error message BC30648: String constants must end with a double quote.
Which makes no sense since it does end in "

Comment: @JoeBarrett, what version of VB are you using? Mary's code uses a multiline `String` literal but they have only been supported in the last few versions. Before that, you could use an XML literal to avoid having to concatenate multiple literals over multiple lines. See my edit to the answer for an example of that.

Comment: @JoeBarrett Was the double quote error solved by jmcilhiney's edit? Version of Visual Studio before 2015 do not support multi-line strings except as shown by the XML literal method.

Comment: @JoeBarrett Regarding the connection. It is actually better for the connection to be local to the method where it is used so it can be closed and disposed. The connection string can be declared elsewhere.

Comment: I used VS 2019. I haven’t got to try Jm’s solution just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Too long and involved for a comment. You have the following snippet in your code:

```
                  ")" &
                  "VALUES(" &
                  "" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.FName) & ", " &
                  "'" & ReplaceApostrophes(pp.MName) & "', " &
```

That is an error. FName is a string and must be treated in exactly the same manner as you do with MName. It is missing the single quote delimiters.

More generally, this approach relies on converting all your "fields" into literals to embed them as strings within your tsql statement. So the question now becomes how do you "write" a binary literal in tsql. You would do that by generating a string like this: 0x69048AEFDD010E. Documentation for tsql constants is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Knowing that, the next issue is how to do that in your dev language - which is not something I can answer. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/how-to-convert-an-array-of-bytes-into-a-string) look promising.

But before you go down this path, use parameterization and you NEVER have to deal with this ever again.

Comment: I will add that the current approach may fail depending on the size of your image.

Answer (score 0):

I come from a MSAccess background, so I code quite much  the same way I did in VBA or now with VB.net

Here the code I would use:

```
    Dim sFields() As String

    sFields = Split("FName,MName,LName,Suffix,Address,AddressExt,City,State,Zip,LawFirm,AddedDate,AddedBy", ",")

    Dim rst As DataTable
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

    rst = MyrstEdit("select * from AuthAccessID where id = 0", da, strcon)

    With rst.Rows.Add
        For Each s In sFields
            .Item(s) = GetValue(pp, s)
        Next
    End With
    da.Update(rst)
```

And I have two helper routines. The first one gets any class property by a "string" value.

Since by luck, you have field names and the class members are the same!

```
Public Function GetValue(ByRef parent As Object, ByVal fieldName As String) As Object

    Dim field As FieldInfo = parent.[GetType]().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    Return field.GetValue(parent)

End Function
```

And then I have a datable routine - that gets me the data table, and is this:

```
Public Function MyrstEdit(strSQL As String, ByRef oReader As SqlDataAdapter) As DataTable

    Dim mycon As New SqlConnection(strCon)
    oReader = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, mycon)
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Dim cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(oReader)
    Try
        oReader.Fill(rstData)
        oReader.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = True
    Catch
    End Try
    Return rstData

End Function
```

So, to get  all the data types and structure? I  pass a dummy sql that returns no rows. (no rows are returned, but we DO GET the valuable table data types when we do this dummy table pull!). In most cases, if the PK  is a autonumber, then I use id = 0.

that same MyRstEdit() code bit has tons of uses! You can now deal with a table in a nice structure, loop it, shove it into a combo box, or datagrid. And as it shows, also allows editing of the data - all with type checking.

The REAL trick and tip I am sharing here? Break out your common data routines to about 2-3 routines like MyRstEdit().

That way, you really don't have to deal with messy in-line sql, or every time you need to work on a table, you don't wire truckloads of code. And the real beauty here is that data typing is done for you - you don't have line after line of parameters, nor line after line of data typing for each column.

So, I hope this post gives you some ideas. But it also nice since I get to code much like I did in MSAccess, and that includes writing VERY little code for updates such as this.

The ideas here are just that - a different approach. The other approaches here are also just fine. (but are quite a bit more code then I perfer).

There are times when using a data table is a rather nice - and I think this is such an example.

And while I am oh so often used to referencing columns as a table collection? The cool trick here is I am also referencing each member of the class with a string too!